# Require Attributes in Where Clause (Redshift)

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to create a table in Redshift that requires users to filter on a specific field? We have a large table and don't want people accidentally querying it without specifying a date range.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is such an option to have mandatory where clause while running queries on a table. There are some data visualization tools like [Looker](http://www.looker.com/docs/reference/explore-params/always_filter), which can configure to query redshift tables using mandatory where clauses, including a default value.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no ability within Redshift to "force" the use of a WHERE statement when querying a table.

You would need to enforce this in a 'higher level' tool that construct the SQL for the user (if any).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be periodically query stv_recent to find out what sql commands are running, and cancel the ones that don't have a date range.